Time is out of sync on Windows 11 PCs
I have two Windows 11 PCs on my desk; they are connected to the same switch & internet connection, and both use all the same security/firewall tools & configurations. Every week or two, they will be a full minute or more off in time from one another. This causes issues with several tools I use.
Both are up to date on all software, BIOS, etc. I have them set to synch automatically - I have tried several time servers, most recently time4.google.com.
What is wrong?  and/or How can I force them to synch properly?

Are these laptops or desktops? With a clock going off so fast, you should probably check the battery for the one that goes slower. There is a root problem that really should be solved, but...
In order to mitigate or control the problem, you could create a scheduled task that resyncs the clocks daily.
Create a new scheduled task, perhaps set to trigger each time you logon (if you logon daily) or just daily when you're logged on (if you leave yourself logged in) and in that task you'll set two actions.

First action Start a Program is %windir%\system32\sc.exe and Arguments are w32time task_started. This will make sure the time service is running.
Second action Start a Program is %windir%\system32\w32tm.exe and Arguments are /resync. This triggers the resync.


My first instinct is the RTC/CMOS bettery, but a minute sounds too small

Yea, but a minute over a week is far more than a normal deviation. There could be power issues with the computer as well, though I'd expect that to result in crashes and other symptoms.
